# AWS IoT, SQS queue and Wrong time in notification bar

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, notifications, queue

if we assume that two devices are **connected** to AWS IoT: raspberry pi 3(i.e RPI3) and Android app. 
 wheThere will be no problem for the phone app to receive a message from the RPI3 mesasge using a chain or a flow of this kind: 
Rpi 3<--> MQTT  > IoT topic > Rules> SNS > Push Notification Service > Android app

The phone app, in this case, will be  to show a notificaiton bar with the time the message was received. However, **when the phone is "disconnected**, f, AWS uses SQS queue (i.e offline requests with draining) to put published messages in the queue, and once the phone is connected, the phone receives the message that was put in the queue.

**The problem** is that when the messages is delivered to the phone after  the phone connects to IoT, it  might arrive some t seconds or minutes later.
*if I really want to show a notification bar that a message was received from RPI3, then notification bar will show the time when message was received by the app, not the time the message was put in the buffer (i.e original time)*

**Now,** does AWS provide am method or a way to know when a message is put in the buffer? if yes, then how we can show the right time on the notification bar in Android